# Browser scales content to double size on 4k monitor

Tags: html, web, browser, scaling

I started to learn some html and css to build my Portfolio as ui designer.
Now i have a problem with scaling on my 4k display.
When i make a div container with the height of 100px it shows up as 200px in my browser.
I have no Problem with other websites. What can i do ?
I already tried to "deactivate scaling on high dpi.